# Iterate and adding value to result

Tags: python, r, for-loop

Simple question. What I try to achieve is this:

```
p1 <- 1
p2 <- p1 + 1.5
p3 <- p2 + 1.5
```

But then in a For loop for 50 points and each point stored in a list. Using this code I only add 1.5 to the orignal number (p1) 50 times:

```
for (i in 1:50){
  list[[i]] <- p1 + 1.5
}
```

How would i be able to add 1.5 to each next point and store in a list?
Can be R or Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sequence of numbers using the `seq()` function, e.g.

`seq(from=1, by=1.5, length.out = 50)`

If you specifically want this to be a list, rather than a vector, you can convert by doing:

`lapply(seq(from=1, by=1.5, length.out = 50), I)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using list comprehension:

```
x = [x * 1.5 + 1 for x in range(50)]
```